# Load and keep Micronaut required resources on startup

Tags: java, memory, jvm, garbage-collection, micronaut

I have a simple Micronaut microservice which support POST/GET/PUT and DELETE for a simple Contact entity. It operates with

- MongoDB (Atlas)
- Redis (Aiven)
- ElasticSearch (https://www.elastic.co/)

I've created a Docker image of the microservice using this base image:

```
FROM alpine:latest
FROM openjdk:17-alpine
RUN apk --no-cache add curl
RUN apk --no-cache add bash
```

And using the jib-maven-plugin:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
     <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <configuration>
          <from>
               <image>base-image-from-docker-hub</image>
          </from>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The microservice is deployed and exposed successfully using an Ingress and K8S Nginx Ingress-Controller and the API is successfully functioning.

However, there's a significant latency change, the first call takes 2.8s in average and the subsequent calls take less than half a second.

I tried to run the microservice locally and analyzed the JVM Process using a Profiler and I noticed that the process starts with a Non-Heap memory of 68mb and when calling the POST endpoint for the first time, it increases to 120mb. I concluded that there are some classes loaded upon receiving the first request.

Is there a way to instruct Micronaut to have a ready-to-operate service right after the startup (loading all necessary resources) ?
I don't mind waiting a couple of seconds before the service is ready to process requests with the lowest possible latency even when receiving the very first request.

I've thought about a Fake API Call On-Statup which warmups the service, but can I ensure that the JVM won't GC the resources and bringing the service back to same point it was in the beginning if it doesn't receive any request for a certain period ?